# VBA run-time Error when using a variable in XLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill in a range of cells with a XLOOKUP formula using VBA. I will be using a different file every day, so I would like to use a variable for the date portion of the filename. However, I keep running into a run-time error (1004: Application-defined or object-defined error) when I run the code below. Everything works as expected until I get to the last step of filling in column V with the XLOOKUP formula.

Code:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, filename As String, reportDate As String          

Call getReportDate(reportDate) 'UserForm where user enters date of report
 
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Sheets("OCI").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row     
filename = "report_name_" & reportDate & ".xlsx"     
 
Range("V2:V" & lastRow).Select 
Selection.Value = "=XLOOKUP(@A:A, ""[" & filename & "]Sheetname""!$L:$L, ""[" & filename & "]Sheetname""!$N:$N)"
```

I have tried hard coding that line with the actual filename and it works perfectly. But since I will be using a different file everyday, I would like to use a variable that holds the date as a string.

Comment: `Range("V2:V" & lastRow).Formula= "=XLOOKUP(@A:A, [" & filename & "]Sheetname!$L:$L, [" & filename & "]Sheetname!$N:$N)"`

Comment: Thank you! I had to add single quotes for the filename and sheet name. Here is the final solution that worked:

Range("V2:V" & lastRow).Formula= "=XLOOKUP(@A:A, '[" & filename & "]Sheetname'!$L:$L, '[" & filename & "]Sheetname'!$N:$N)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another method without using select (which is preferred) would be looping through Range("V2:V" & lastRow) like this:

```
Dim lastRow As Long, filename As String, reportDate As String                  

Call getReportDate(reportDate) 'UserForm where user enters date of report
 
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Sheets("OCI").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row         
filename = "report_name_" & reportDate & ".xlsx"         

Dim rng as range, c as range 
set rng = Range("V2:V" & lastRow) 
For each c in rng
c.Formula = "=XLOOKUP(@A:A, ""[" & filename & "]Sheetname""!$L:$L, ""[" & filename & "]Sheetname""!$N:$N)"

Next c
```